# Calculating triple integral between paraboloid and plane

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

I have the following integral:

$$ \iiint zdxdydz$$

on the area bound by the following surfaces: $$z=\frac{a^2}{b^2} (x^2+y^2)$$

$$z=a$$

$$a,b>0$$

The first surface is a paraboloid and the second is a plane. Now, this is how I proceeded:

Introducing cylindrical coordinates:

$x=r\cos\phi$

$y=r\sin\phi$

$|J| = r$

now, what I did next was substitute $z=a$ in the equation of the paraboloid. I got that $x^2+y^2 = \dfrac{b^2}{a}$, or that $r=\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a}}$ which led me to believe that $$r\in \left[0, \frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}\right]$$

$$\phi \in \left[0, 2\pi\right]$$

Now regarding $z$, I know that it is bound from below by the paraboloid and from above by the plane, so I deduced that the boundaries are: $$z\in \left[\frac{a^2}{b^2}r^2, a\right]$$.

My integral gets the form:

$$\int_0^{\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{r\frac{a^2}{b^2}}^a zr dz d\phi dr$$

Which evaluates to $\dfrac{\pi ab^2}{3}$, but my workbook solution is $\dfrac{a^2 b^2 \pi}{4}$.

Could anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: You need to show your calcs

Comment: You wrote $a,b>0$, but there is no $b$ in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos typo! Instead of the x squared it should be b squared in the denominator of the equation of paraboloid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question reads over the given *area*. To avoid any confusion, it should rather read over the given *region* bound by given surfaces.

The workbook answer is wrong. While it says integrand is $z$ but it gives you answer for integrating $z^2$ over the given region.

I just validate going in the order $dr \ dz \ d\phi$,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{a} \int_0^{\sqrt{b^2 z / a^2}}  r \ z \ dr \ dz \ d\phi = \dfrac{\pi a b^2}{3}$

which matches your answer.

Whereas,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{a} \int_0^{\sqrt{b^2 z / a^2}}  r \ z^2 \ dr \ dz \ d\phi = \frac{\pi a^2b^2}{4}$

Comment: Thanks! English is not really my native language so I have problems with some of the concepts! Accepted.

Comment: @johndoe understood. By the way, I see you are in triple integral over 3D regions now. I hope you are able to follow answers, like yesterday what you posted for sphere and paraboloid intersection. I try and give some description so you can follow but if anytime you want to understand better, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: thank you very much! I will admit that triple integrals (over 3D regions) are a bit harder than what I was used to, and since I am still learning I oftentimes get stuck. You've been a great help!